# Profiling JVMs with JVMTI, how to distinguish the different JVMs?

Tags: java, jvmti

I am writing a profiler with the aid of the JVM TI.

In C++ I have written a simple agent, which writes the information collected to a socket. With Java Swing I have built a simple GUI which reads these data from a socket to visualize it.

However I am facing some usability issues. I would like to provide the functionality to start profiling a Java application on request. There is the [Attach API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/attach/index.html) which provides the possibility to inject an agent into a **running** JVM.

But to start a new Java program and inject the agent is a little bit more complicated. One way would be, to make a call to the command line and start the Java program from the GUI Profiler:

```
java -agentlib:agent Program
```

I kind of dislike this idea, because it is somehow *hacky* but I see no other way, do you?

To summarize I need two ways to start profiling a JVM:

1. Start a Java applicatiom from the scratch and start profiling it directly
2. Attach to a running JVM and inject the agent to start profiling it

Further, I would be in need to distinguish the different JVMs which I inspect, but how to do that? There no unique identifier for the different JVMs. The **Attach API** gives the possibility to list the different JVMs with their *name* and *id*, but what to do in the first case? Is it possible to inject the agent with **arguments**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the local process identification (pid) and the network address to uniquely identfy the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

You can also generate your own GUID in the Agent_OnLoad and use that for logging. this way if your some of your processes have short lives and others long lives you can distinguish between recycled PIDS.